# edit a Gerber file

Tags: pcb, gerber

I want to create my own PCB (30x30 millimeters) using a free software a found online; this software give me the gerber file only after I make the order from their company, but the price is very high compared to others cheap PCB printer website.
My idea is to pay the first company to print my PCB so I receive also the gerber file, and then to modify it to put 9 copies of the same circuit into a 100x100 millimeter PCB and print this from a cheaper company.

Do you think is this idea possible?

Comment: How is it free if you have to pay the company to get gerbers? Why not just generate gerbers with other software? You can send a 30x30mm gerber to a company and ask them to panelize if for you.

Answer (score 6):

There is free software that can you can use to create PCB's and to paneling as well. Example: [KiCAD](https://www.kicad.org/), Open source and multi OS support and it can generate Gerber.